# Multiple values in cells - How to restructure them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this:

```
ID                          Fruit                   Consumer 

01                apple, banana, banana           user1, user2, user13
02                banana, apple, pineapple        user3, user5, user8
03                pear, apple, apple, banana      user27, user1, user2, user33
```

I need this for my following steps:

```
ID         apple            banana               pineapple             pear
01      user1            user2, user13            Nobody               Nobody
02      user5               user3                 user8                Nobody
03      user1, user2        user33                Nobody               user27
```

I dont know how to map the users to the fruit columns.
Any ideas?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly?

Comment: Its a restructure problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set ID as index

`df = df.set_index('ID')`

Then parse the fruit and user columns. Pivot on the fruit columns and aggregate with `,`

`df = pd.concat([df['Consumer'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack(), df['Fruit'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()], axis=1).rename(columns={0: 'user', 1: 'fruit'}).pivot_table(index=['ID'], columns=['fruit'], values='user', aggfunc=lambda x: ','.join(x), fill_value='Nobody')`

```
fruit        apple        banana    pear pineapple
ID                                                
1            user1  user2,user13  Nobody    Nobody
2            user5         user3  Nobody     user8
3      user1,user2        user33  user27    Nobody
```

Comment: You can add it as a parameter to the `pivot_table` function, `fill_value='Nobody'`